# can i / how can i share authentication/SSO over different CAS-Services?

Tags: cas

I have 2 CAS-Services (CAS 6.0.3) registered (via JSON) with different serviceIds and AuthenticationHandlers and so on. I can authenticate again each of the two services separately (e.g. cas/login?service=http...service1). But when i try to access the second Service (cas/login?service=http...service2) after i already authenticated again the other service i get this error Message:

**Ticket ... does not match supplied service. The original service was ... and the supplied service was ...**

Info: all "..." matches / are the same Service-ID-String. The internal Code für the error-message is "INVALID_SERVICE"

CAS thinks "all right, you are already logged in and i can redirect you directly to your service". It even makes a SessionToken for validation and then redirects. But when the second services Validates the ticket, the error message apears.

Is there a posibility to allow Service1 and Service2 to use the same "SSO Context" / CAS-Session / allow login in service2 after logged in in Service1? 
Is there maybe a RegisteredServiceProperty for this topic that i can use in my service-JSON configuration?

I already read everything on this page: https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/index.html and even tried to search the source-code for such validation-options..

These are the last lines in my Log with "trace"-Level enabled:

```
=============================================================
WHO: myuser
WHAT: ST-2-tNnqqJfwFeSSAqaQf-LBTF7AvsMLAPTOP-3DHMD58D
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_VALIDATE_SUCCESS
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed May 15 11:02:14 CEST 2019
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================


2019-05-15 11:02:14,965 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.validation.AbstractCasProtocolValidationSpecification] - <Is validation specification set to enforce [renew] protocol behavior? [no]. Is assertion issued from a new login? [no]>
2019-05-15 11:02:14,965 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.validation.Cas20WithoutProxyingValidationSpecification] - <Number of chained authentications in the assertion [1]>
2019-05-15 11:02:14,965 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.validation.AbstractCasProtocolValidationSpecification] - <Validation specification is satisfied by the produced assertion>
2019-05-15 11:02:14,965 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.services.AbstractServicesManager] - <No environments are assigned to service [myservice]>
2019-05-15 11:02:14,965 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.validation.RegisteredServiceRequiredHandlersServiceTicketValidationAuthorizer] - <Evaluating service [AbstractWebApplicationService(id=https://blub.blub, originalUrl=https://blub.blub, artifactId=ST-2-tNnqqJfwFeSSAqaQf-LBTF7AvsMLAPTOP-3DHMD58D, principal=null, source=service, loggedOutAlready=false, format=XML, attributes={})] to ensure required authentication handlers can satisfy assertion>
2019-05-15 11:02:14,965 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.util.CollectionUtils] - <Converting multi-valued element [[MailboxAuthenticationHandler]]>
2019-05-15 11:02:14,966 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.web.view.CasReloadableMessageBundle] - <Examining language bundle [classpath:custom_messages_de] for the code [INVALID_SERVICE]>
2019-05-15 11:02:14,966 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.web.view.CasReloadableMessageBundle] - <Examining language bundle [classpath:messages_de] for the code [INVALID_SERVICE]>
```

The validation-response is: (the error message is in german but it is the same /  "INVALID_SERVICE"-error):

```
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
    <cas:authenticationFailure code="INVALID_SERVICE">Ticket &#39;ST-2-tNnqqJfwFeSSAqaQf-LBTF7AvsMLAPTOP-3DHMD58D&#39; passt nicht zum angegebenen Service. Der urspr&amp;uuml;ngliche Service war &#39;https://blub.blub&#39; und der &amp;uuml;bermittelte Service war &#39;https://blub.blub&#39;.</cas:authenticationFailure>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this (mis)behavior.
It seams that it is not possible to use different AuthenticationHandler on different Services even when these custom handlers have the same code / attributes inside.

It would by quite nice when "CAS" would show a more precise error message (in the log) in this case or if this would be somewhere documented.